# A question regarding the Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

This is probably a very stupid/absurd question....

The theorem states that every bounded real sequence has a convergent subsequence. We further know that every sequence of real numbers has a monotone subsequence.

My question is, why not simply use the fact that a bounded monotone sequence is convergent to prove the theorem in a simpler way?

Indeed the fact is used in the Cantor Intersection Theorem, but is the 'fact' alone not enough to prove BW theorem? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the proof of the Theorem you are referring to? There is more than one way to prove it, so we can't really comment about a specific proof without you stating it.

Comment: How do you intend to apply this fact to a bounded real sequence? You must first extract a monotone subsequence, as you stated. Maybe you should be a lot more explicit, if you have something in mind.

Comment: @TedShifrin it can be extracted i think. Using "peaks" of the sequence.

Comment: Some authors prove BW in exactly this way (Bartle and Sherbert, e.g.).

Comment: @Melody the proof that uses the Cantor Intersection Theorem by bisecting the interval that contains the elements of the sequence.

Comment: @DavidMitra wait a second... Is my thinking valid?

Comment: Yes. Of course, you need to establish (as can be done) the two facts you mentioned.

Comment: @DavidMitra of course, I cannot take the fact for granted. I need to establish first that indeed every real sequence has a monotone subsequence. (I have that proof). Thank you for clearing the lingering doubt. :)

Comment: @Subhasis Biswas My guess then, is that Cantor's Intersection Theorem generalizes to compact sets in arbitrary metric spaces. Using this generalization of Cantor's Theorem you can generalize Bolzano-Weierstrass to compact sets in arbitrary Metric spaces. That is, if $X$ is a metric space $C\subseteq X$ is compact, and $a_n\in C,$ then $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence.

The Monotone Subsequence property cannot generalize, as monotone sequences don't even make sense in arbitrary metric spaces.

Comment: Yes! Taking complex numbers for example (where no ordering can be defined)... But it is indeed a metric space wrt the standard Euclidean Norm. Any mistakes in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing stupid or absurd in that question. Actually, some textbooks prove the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem along this line. But it is not trivial or obvious that every sequence of real numbers has a monotone subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

We *can* prove the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem this way. First, we prove that every sequence has a monotone subsequence, and from this it follows that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence, by the Monotone Convergence theorem.

**Here’s a proof sketch of the first part:**

Let $(a_n)$ be a real sequence.

We say that a term $a_i$ in the sequence is *dominant* if $j > i \implies a_j \leq a_i$.

There are two possibilities for the set of all dominant terms.

1) The set is infinite. In this case, the subsequence formed from all the terms in this set is a decreasing sequence.

2) The set is finite. In this case, there must be a point in the sequence after which all terms are not dominant. So take a term $a_i$ after this point. Now, since $j > i \implies a_j \leq a_i$ for $a_i$ dominant we can find a term $a_j$ in the sequence that is greater than or equal to $a_i$. Iterate this process, and the subsequence formed will be an increasing sequence.

In either case, we have a monotone subsequence.

Comment: Very much the standard proof!